# Open automatically a downloaded file

Tags: javascript, html, file

As of today, the regular procedure to install a downloaded file in a webpage has 2 steps:

1. Download the file (automatically or by clicking)
2. Click to open the file

Is there a way I can automatically perform the step #2?
So the user doesn't has to click the downloaded file to start the installation.

**NOTE: He stills has to accept the installation (fine by me).**

Comment: Set it as default open in the browser.

Comment: Due to security concerns, I don't think it is possible to auto run the file.

Comment: (of course the webpage itself can't do it)

Comment: @user202729 can you elaborate more?

Comment: @HillelGarcia A website can not open (downloaded) files on the computer of the user that is visiting your website. As mentioned before this is due to security reasons. Maybe there are some browsers that could do it. But that would require a specific browser from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many browsers (most) have the option to automatically open files once downloaded. However, this privilege is not provided to webpages due to security concerns.

Just imagine, you open a website and suddenly ALL programs on your computer start up and your computer crashes.

That's why.